# CkEditor - converting hex code to html characters

Tags: html, email, cakephp, ckeditor, amazon-ses

I'm facing a problem with CkEditor. I generates html code (html email string) and show that string into Ckeditor.

```
    $message = "<html><body>
                 bla.. bla.. bla.. bla.. 
                 &#10025;&#10025;&#10025;
                 bla.. bla.. bla.. bla.. 
             </body></html>";
    echo $this->Form->textarea('emailContent', array(
        'class' => 'ckeditor', 
        'value' => $message
```

));

I'm using html star's hex code in my email string But the problem here is when I show my generated string to CKeditor, all '&# 10025;' gets converted into '✩' and when I send this text as html email I get '????' in the email.

I have added below code in the email text string too but still.

```
   "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />"
```

Using Amazon SES RawEmail to send the mail.

How I can prevent CKeditor to send hex values rather the characters .

Comment: If you get stuck, you can always convert them back afterwards with something like php's [htmlentites()](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: Thanks.. but it didn't worked. When I email the text after passing it from the function you mentioned, the email don't show up as html instead I gets html codes.